# Is there a SELECT statement to subtract rows of the same column?

Tags: mysql

[image]

Column 1 is the `mem_id`, Column 2 is the `Transaction type` C and D, and Column 3 is the `Amount Owed`. So I want to return Column 3 "Amount Owed", but it has to be C-D in Column 2 for each member. thanks, I hope that helps.

Comment: Subtract them from what?

Comment: Michael, I edited the question. I hope that helps.

Comment: `SELECT MemName, MemTot from TableName where transtype in ('C', 'D');`

Comment: Yes, I posted a screen shot to help explain better,

Comment: As I understand it, you have multiple rows for each mem_id, each marked with either C or D, and you want to return rows containing C - D for each mem_id. Is that right? It would _really_ help if you added an example.

Comment: Please edit you previous question and add this image there itself, that will be help in getting what output you are looking for

Comment: Make up your mind: do you want C-D or do you want D-C? Martin's solution is correct, and if it doesn't work, then your question is unclear.

Answer (score 8):

If I understood your question correctly...

```
SELECT mem_id, 
       Sum(CASE TranType 
             WHEN 'C' THEN Amount 
             WHEN 'D' THEN -Amount 
           END) AS Amount_Owed 
FROM   YourTable 
GROUP  BY mem_id;
```

Comment: I understood the same.

Comment: It's running, but not giving me the correct out put, i'll keep tweaking it, thanks again.

Comment: @LisaChise can you add some rows of example data to your question along with expected results for that data?

Comment: Hi Martin. An example of the expected output is. let's just use member1, amountowed column would be D - C of column Transtype, which will produce 1129.80 - 750.90 in column AmountOwed..thanks

Comment: I think you just got it backwards... C is minus and D is plus, so just switch the minus sign from D to C

Comment: @Falco - Possibly. Both permutations have been mentioned by the OP on this page. Without non obfuscated example dummy data and desired results for that data difficult to know what they want...

Answer (score 1):

For the Previous Question

```
SELECT MemName, 
       Sum(CASE TransType 
             WHEN 'D' THEN MemTot
             WHEN 'C' THEN -MemTot 
           END) AS MemTot
FROM   YourTable 
GROUP  BY MemName;
```

---

OR

```
SELECT 
  MemName
  COALESCE(Y.MemTot- (SELECT Y.MemTot
                     FROM Yourtable AS Y1
                     WHERE Y2.TransType =C),
           Y.Memtot) AS Memtot
FROM YourTable AS Y
GROUP  BY MemName;
```

Comment: I tried this but not getting the correct output, I'm still working. thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error, or what output you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just not the correct output. For example, member1 output should be D - C in Transtype column, which is 1129.80 - 750.90 in MemTot

Answer (score 0):

Would that work? :)
It does work in SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT t.mem_id, (MAX(CASE WHEN t.transtype = 'D' THEN t.MemTot END) - MAX(CASE WHEN t.transtype = 'C' THEN t.MemTot END)) AS Diff
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS mem_id, 'D' AS transtype, 1129.80 AS MemTot
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'C', 750.90
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'D', 568.60
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'C', 385.95
) AS T
GROUP BY t.mem_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a running total for each row, you have to set up a user variable. The purpose of the user variable is to keep the total value after each row like a spreadsheet cell.

## PROPOSED CODE

```
SET @rt = 0;
SELECT *,(@rt:=@rt+IF(transtype='D',MemTot,-MemTot)) RunningTotal
FROM member_trans;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

I am using the first ten(10) rows from your question

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS lisachise;
CREATE DATABASE lisachise;
USE lisachise
CREATE TABLE member_trans
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
transtype CHAR(1),MemTot FLOAT,
PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO member_trans (transtype,MemTot) VALUES
('D',1129.80),('C',750.90),
('D',568.80),('C',385.95),
('D',991.50),('C',414.00),
('D',847.60),('C',577.80),
('D',94.60),('C',57.45);
SELECT * FROM member_trans;
```

## SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS lisachise;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE lisachise;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> USE lisachise
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE member_trans
    -> (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> transtype CHAR(1),MemTot FLOAT,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO member_trans (transtype,MemTot) VALUES
    -> ('D',1129.80),('C',750.90),
    -> ('D',568.80),('C',385.95),
    -> ('D',991.50),('C',414.00),
    -> ('D',847.60),('C',577.80),
    -> ('D',94.60),('C',57.45);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM member_trans;
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | transtype | MemTot |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | D         | 1129.8 |
|  2 | C         |  750.9 |
|  3 | D         |  568.8 |
|  4 | C         | 385.95 |
|  5 | D         |  991.5 |
|  6 | C         |    414 |
|  7 | D         |  847.6 |
|  8 | C         |  577.8 |
|  9 | D         |   94.6 |
| 10 | C         |  57.45 |
+----+-----------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## PROPOSED CODE EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @rt = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT *,(@rt:=@rt+IF(transtype='D',MemTot,-MemTot)) RunningTotal
    -> FROM member_trans;
+----+-----------+--------+--------------------+
| id | transtype | MemTot | RunningTotal       |
+----+-----------+--------+--------------------+
|  1 | D         | 1129.8 |  1129.800048828125 |
|  2 | C         |  750.9 |  378.9000244140625 |
|  3 | D         |  568.8 |  947.7000122070312 |
|  4 | C         | 385.95 |             561.75 |
|  5 | D         |  991.5 |            1553.25 |
|  6 | C         |    414 |            1139.25 |
|  7 | D         |  847.6 | 1986.8499755859375 |
|  8 | C         |  577.8 | 1409.0499877929688 |
|  9 | D         |   94.6 | 1503.6499862670898 |
| 10 | C         |  57.45 | 1446.1999855041504 |
+----+-----------+--------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

To format the output better, here is the same query but with formatting

```
SET @rt = 0;
SELECT *,LPAD(FORMAT((@rt:=@rt+IF(transtype='D',MemTot,-MemTot)),2),10,' ') RunningTotal
FROM member_trans;
```

and here is its output

```
mysql> SET @rt = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT *,LPAD(FORMAT((@rt:=@rt+IF(transtype='D',MemTot,-MemTot)),2),10,' ') RunningTotal
    -> FROM member_trans;
+----+-----------+--------+--------------+
| id | transtype | MemTot | RunningTotal |
+----+-----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | D         | 1129.8 |   1,129.80   |
|  2 | C         |  750.9 |     378.90   |
|  3 | D         |  568.8 |     947.70   |
|  4 | C         | 385.95 |     561.75   |
|  5 | D         |  991.5 |   1,553.25   |
|  6 | C         |    414 |   1,139.25   |
|  7 | D         |  847.6 |   1,986.85   |
|  8 | C         |  577.8 |   1,409.05   |
|  9 | D         |   94.6 |   1,503.65   |
| 10 | C         |  57.45 |   1,446.20   |
+----+-----------+--------+--------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```